# Tool bar in IOS 6 not working properly

Tags: ios6, uiview, uibarbuttonitem, toolbar

i am adding Tool bar to a UIView like :

```
 UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44);
    UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(sendAction)];

    UIBarButtonItem *button2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancelAction)];

    [toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, nil]];
    [toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button2, nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

But Buttons are always in disabled form..i donot know why this always happens. i have cleaned my project as well.

Comment: What do you mean "disabled form" -- do you mean that tapping the button doesn't run the action method?  Do you see both buttons?  I think your code to set the items should be "[toolbar setItems:@[button1, button2];".

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
    button1,button2, nil];
[self.toolbar addsubview:toolbaritems

Add this line of code

Comment: You are wrong. [self.toolbar addsubview:toolbaritems]; we cann't do this way as toolbaritems is an array not UIView.